# Map is displaying incorrectly when adding navbar to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I have added navbar on a google map page that fetches data from external json file and it is not displaying the map correctly.Also,it says that empty string is passed in getelementbyID in jquery mobile file.Is there a way to fix this?

```
<html>
     <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

      <style type="text/css">
         html { height: 100% }
         body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
         #map_canvas {height: 100%;margin:5% }
      </style>
      <link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />

      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=something&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {

        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.66207, -79.37617),
          zoom: 17,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);

        $.getJSON('bikeshare.json', function(data) { 


            $.each( data.stationBeanList, function(i, value) {


                var locationLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: locationLatLong,
                map: map,
                icon:"img/bike.png",
                title:"Bikes available: "+JSON.stringify(value.availableBikes)
                });


                  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

                    content:"Docks Available:  "+JSON.stringify(value.availableDocks)

                  });

                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {

                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

                  });



            });


      });



      }
    </script>
  </head>
      <body onload="initialize()">
        <div data-role="header" >
        <h3>BIKESHARE</h3>
        <div data-role="navbar" data-position="fixed">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Home</a>   </li>
        <li><a>Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="locations.html">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href="map.html">Map</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
       <div   data-role="content" id="map_canvas" ></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.   We need your JSON (at least a sample that demonstrates the issue).

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS issue.

Change this:

```css
#map_canvas {height: 100%;margin:5% }
```

to:

```css
#map_canvas {height:700px; margin:5%}
```

Or an alternative would be to calculate a new height and set it before calling the `initialize()` function:

```
 //Add this line or something similar which calculate div height in the initialize function
 $('#map_canvas').css('height', ($(window).height()-10) + 'px');
```

## New Function

```
function initialize() {
    $('#map_canvas').css('height', ($(window).height() - 10) + 'px');
    var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.66207, -79.37617),
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
    $.getJSON('bikeshare.json', function (data) {
        $.each(data.stationBeanList, function (i, value) {
            var locationLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: locationLatLong,
                map: map,
                icon: "img/bike.png",
                title: "Bikes available: " + JSON.stringify(value.availableBikes)
            });
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "Docks Available:  " + JSON.stringify(value.availableDocks)
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        });
    });
}
```